# Pre-push Git hook to determine if branch name is valid

Tags: git, bash

I want to write a Bash script to test a regex against a branch name with a Git pre-push hook. I have read the pre-push documentation but I am having trouble getting the hook into my application. Anyone have any suggestions.

```
local_branch = $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
valid_chars = $(^[a-z0-9-]+$)

if [[ "$local_branch" =~ valid_chars]]; then
  echo 'Failed to push.  Branch is using incorrect characters.  Valid        Characters are lower case (a-z), numbers (0-9) and dashes(-).  Please rename branch to continue'
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: What issue are you having exactly?

Comment: @Whymarrh I've added my code but i can't seem to get it to fire when i git push origin <branch>

Comment: [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) is your friend in the future.

Answer (score 8):

Running the script you have above results in various errors. I am also not sure why you are executing `^[a-z0-9-]+$` and storing the result in `valid_chars`. Nonetheless:

- You probably want to exit with an error if the branch name does not match the regex
- You're missing a `$` prefix for `valid_chars` in your test
- `if [[ "$local_branch" =~ valid_chars]]; then` should have a space inside the `]]`

As always, ensure that the script is under `.git/hooks/pre-push`, named correctly, and is marked as executable.

The following works for me (I have left the sample hook comment in because I'm lazy):

```
#!/bin/bash

# An example hook script to verify what is about to be pushed.  Called by "git
# push" after it has checked the remote status, but before anything has been
# pushed.  If this script exits with a non-zero status nothing will be pushed.
#
# This hook is called with the following parameters:
#
# $1 -- Name of the remote to which the push is being done
# $2 -- URL to which the push is being done
#
# If pushing without using a named remote those arguments will be equal.
#
# Information about the commits which are being pushed is supplied as lines to
# the standard input in the form:
#
#   <local ref> <local sha1> <remote ref> <remote sha1>
#
# This sample shows how to prevent push of commits where the log message starts
# with "WIP" (work in progress).

local_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
valid_chars="^[a-z0-9-]+$"
message='...'

if [[ ! $local_branch =~ $valid_chars ]]
then
    printf '%s\n' "$message"
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Whymarrh.  I also had my code in a scripts folder inside my git hooks.  ended up having to put

Comment: Thanks @Whymarrh.  I ended up getting that late last night and then realized that my main problem was the code was sitting inside a scripts folder inside my githooks folder so i ended up adding a pre-push file which included this

      CURRENT_DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )

      $CURRENT_DIR/scripts/check-valid-branch-name $@

Comment: Use $1 instead of HEAD. Because maybe the pushed branch is not the current branch.(the first parameter passed to git hook is the branch name)